# Backup attached database file(.mdf) using c# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, winforms

I was trying to create a backup of a database in my Winforms application. But it is not working

This is my code:

```
cn.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = cn;
cmd.CommandText=@"BACKUP DATABASE Database1.mdf TO DISK = 'C:\db1.bak'";
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.close();
cn.Close();
```

Here `cn` is `SqlConnection`. `cmd` is `SqlCommand` and `dr` is `SqlDataReader`. Please give me a solution.

Comment: Please give more details. What is not working about it? is there an error? Does it just not work? Are you checking the backup locaiton on the SERVER and not on the computer that is connecting to the server (If they're different)?

Comment: What do you mean it is now working? You got any exception or error message?

Comment: Way too vague - e.g.: is the SQL Server instance running on your own machine, or on a remote server?

Comment: `BACKUP DATABASE [Database1] TO DISK = 'C:\db1.bak'`

Comment: @Devart has the right idea - you don't refer to the .mdf file when doing a native backup, you refer to the name of the database.

Comment: and `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: keep in mind that the `C:\db1.bak` here is ***relative to the SQL server***. Not to the machine that is *making the request*.

Comment: I got the following sqlexception error.
"Incorrect syntax near '.'." 
I dont know whether my code has a syntax/logical error.

Comment: Try to use brackets for database name.

Comment: @Devart when I omit .mdf I got another error!

"Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'Database1'. No entry found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally."

Comment: can somebody give me a simple example for backup command pls...

Comment: The **freely available, comprehensive** documentation called [SQL Server Books Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) on MSDN has ***tons of examples*** - just go use it!

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you use [sql server management objects](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx).

Create method like below

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

public void BackupDatabase(string databaseName, string userName, string password, string serverName, string destinationPath)
{
    //Define a Backup object variable.
    Backup sqlBackup = new Backup();

    //Specify the type of backup, the description, the name, and the database to be backed up.
    sqlBackup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
    sqlBackup.BackupSetDescription = "BackUp of:" + databaseName + "on" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    sqlBackup.BackupSetName = "FullBackUp";
    sqlBackup.Database = databaseName;

    //Declare a BackupDeviceItem
    BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(destinationPath + "FullBackUp.bak", DeviceType.File);
    //Define Server connection
    ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
    //To Avoid TimeOut Exception
    Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);
    sqlServer.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 60 * 60;
    Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];

    sqlBackup.Initialize = true;
    sqlBackup.Checksum = true;
    sqlBackup.ContinueAfterError = true;

    //Add the device to the Backup object.
    sqlBackup.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
    //Set the Incremental property to False to specify that this is a full database backup.
    sqlBackup.Incremental = false;

    sqlBackup.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
    //Specify that the log must be truncated after the backup is complete.
    sqlBackup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;

    sqlBackup.FormatMedia = false;
    //Run SqlBackup to perform the full database backup on the instance of SQL Server.
    sqlBackup.SqlBackup(sqlServer);
    //Remove the backup device from the Backup object.
    sqlBackup.Devices.Remove(deviceItem);
}
```

For using those namespaces which are show above. You have to add the references of these namespaces. For this-

Go to Your Application and Right Click on References folder and select Add Reference.

Now Go to "Browse" Tab and browse the following path-
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies"

Now Select the following dlls

Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll ,
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll ,
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll ,
Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll ,
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll ,

**Note:** Location of Dlls might be defer according to version of MS SQL Server, i am not sure about it.

Comment: I have one more stupid question! How can I find the password?

Comment: Which password? if you talking about sql server password, that you would have set while installing Sql Server

Comment: I didn't give any! The only thing I did is installing visual studio 2008 professional edition in complete mode.

Comment: I am surprised, then which database backup you want to take, that database should be somewhere inside sql server.

Comment: Aah! My server explorer looks like this(it may help you to find the problem)

DataConnections
-database1.mdf
-Nortwind.mdf

Servers
-mothivihar
I added database1 by add->new item->servicebased database
and northwind by selecting database file
-mothivihar

Comment: look like what?, firest check your code side where you storing data , in sql server datbase or in local sql file provided by visual studio?

Comment: see my edited previous comment

Comment: sorry i didn't get it , i given answer for taking backup of sql server database using c# as you write in question.

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity. my problem comes under 'backup attached database file ,.mdf'